# How to create multiple frontend-editable textfields on one page

Tags: joomla, frontend, joomla-extensions, editing, joomla3.0

I need to have several textfields (may be articles, but not neccessarily) on a page, that is *easily* edited from frontend for registered users.

How do I best achieve this?

It is for Joomla 3.1

Comment: Have you tried a CCK such as:
FLEXIcontent http://www.flexicontent.org/ ?
That gives you extra fields for editing articles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go several ways:

1. Use a cck: this is the easiest, no coding required, browse the JED for Sobi, K2, Zoo, Content builder...
2. Write a simple component: using componentbuilder or the like it won't take long and you'll only need to write very little code if this is the only requirement.
3. Upgrade to J3.2 and use the bundled FOF (by akeeba, introduced in Joomla core as of 3.2); Joomla! 3.2 will be available in 3 days, but you can already download the beta.  With FOF you can achieve much the same as 2. by writing a simple xml file.

Depending on what you plan to do with this data, and your coding skills, the right answer may be any of the above.